# Записать массив в файл в другом формате. Python

Tags: python, массивы, файлы, запись

хочу обратиться с вопросом записи массива в файл в другом формате.
Пример моего кода

```
import random
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']


for i in range(8):
    west = ''
    for rei in range(8):
        b = random.randint(0, 7)
        west = west + list1[b]

        
    new_datas = []
    for item in west:
        new_datas.append({
            'title': [item],
        })

with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\3232.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in new_datas)

print(new_datas)
```

Данный метод записывает файл в таком виде

```
{'title': ['b']}
{'title': ['d']}
{'title': ['e']}
{'title': ['g']}
{'title': ['c']}
{'title': ['f']}
{'title': ['c']}
{'title': ['e']}
```

Хотелось бы получить такой результат:

```
title:b
title:d
title:e
title:g
title:c
title:f
title:c
title:e
```

**Заранее благодарю все, кто будет соучаствовать в моём вопросе. Спасибо!**

Comment: посмотрите на https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, зачем вы формируете данные именно такой структуры, но, допустим, не будем трогать данные, а только вывод:

```
file.writelines(f"{k}:{','.join(v)}\n" for line in new_datas for k,v in line.items())
```

Пример вывода в файл:

```
title:h
title:c
title:g
title:h
title:a
title:g
title:c
title:d
```

Если вдруг `item` будет не один в словаре, этот код выведет их через запятую, вот так:

```
title:a,b,c
```

Comment: "Не очень понятно, зачем вы формируете данные именно такой структуры", создал для примера, что бы понять суть. Благодарю вас!